# How to access 'templating' service not in controller

Tags: symfony

Ok, so the problem is:

I've got some 'order' entity, and it has 'status' property. On changing status, i wanted some other objects to be informed of this event, so i've decided to use Observer pattern. One of the observers notifies clients via email. Now i want to render Email text's from some of the twig templates. As i get from the Book, rendering templates in controllers are done with 'templating' service.

So the question as it follows: How can i access 'templating' service in my Observer class?

Specification:
  I was advised, to implement my Observer as a service, but i'm not sure 'bout that. I've tried to solve this problem, and here is my options:

1. Use Registry. Solution that is straight and hard as rail. I guess it misses the whole point of DI and Service Container. Huge plus of this solution, is that i can access all common services from any point of my application.
2. To pass needed services from the context via constructor, or via setters. This is more like in Sf2 spirit. There comes another list of problems, which are not related to this question field.
3. Use observers as a service. I'm not really sure 'bout this option 'cos, in the book it is written, that service is a *common* functionality, and i don't think that observing entity with number of discrete properties is a common task.

I'm looking for a Sf2 spirit solution, which will be spread over whole project, so all answers with an explanation are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As with any other service in a Symfony2 project, you can access it from within other classes through the dependency injector container. Basically what you would do is register your observer class as a service, and then inject the templating service into your observer service. See the docs for [injecting services](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html#referencing-injecting-services).

If you're not familiar with how Symfony handles dependency injection, I'd suggest reading that entire chapter of the documentation - it's very helpful. Also, if you want to find all the services that are registered for application, you can use the console command `container:debug`. You can also append a service name after that to see detailed info about the service.

**Edit**
I read your changes to the question, but still recommend going down the DI route. That *is* the Symfony2 spirit :) You're worried that your observer isn't common enough to be used as a service, but there's no hard rule saying "You must use this piece of code in X locations in order for it to be 'common'".

Using the DIC comes with another huge benefit - it handles other dependencies for you. Let's say the templating service has 3 services injected into itself. When using the DIC, you don't need to worry about the templating service's dependencies - they are handled for you. All you care about is telling it "inject the templating service into this other service" and Symfony takes care of all the heavy lifting.

If you're really opposed to defining your observer as a service, you can use constructor or setter injection as long as you're within a container-aware context.

Comment: Oh, mb my question was not so concrete, as i wanted. So i'll make some specifications.

Comment: I'll try to use your advice. And I'll share my effort's on a github.